# Validation Engine Returns False When Valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

Validation Engine is returning false when no errors were detected and true when validation is unsuccessful, which is the opposite of what I would expect. The weird part is that the tooltips are correct. Take a look at my example.

[Try the Codepen here.](http://codepen.io/alflenniken/pen/KNrLgX)

This appears to run counter to the Validation Engine documentation. [According to the Validation Engine Docs:](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/)

> #### validate
>
> Validates a form or field, displays error prompts accordingly.
>
> Returns true if the form validates, false if it contains errors.
>   For fields, it returns true on validate and false on errors.
>   When using form validation with ajax, it returns undefined , the result is delivered asynchronously via function options.onAjaxFormComplete.
>
> `alert( $("#formID1").validationEngine('validate') );`
>
> `alert( $("#emailInput").validationEngine('validate') );`

#### HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="billLast_Name"
    class="form-control bill-field validate[required]"
    placeholder="Surname*"
    value=""
    title="Surname"/>
  <button id="validate">Validate</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#validate').on('click', function(){
    var result = $('.bill-field').validationEngine('validate')
    $('#result').html('Validation result is ' + result)
  })
})
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a known issue. The [code base on GitHub](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) includes unresolved [issue #912](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/912) posted Feb. 1, 2016:

> In documentation:
>
> **validate**
>
> Validates a form or field, displays error prompts accordingly.
>
> Returns true if the form validates, false if it contains errors. (correct)
>   **For fields, it returns true on validate and false on errors. (wrong)**
>
> This is actually the other way. On validate it returns false and errors it returns true.

Given the way the documentation is worded, I suspect this is actually a documentation issue rather than a code issue.

Comment: Wow, this seems far too basic to get wrong. I'm not impressed! Oh well, it doesn't really affect me, I can just flip my validation check and drop in a comment explaining the weird logic. Still, it seems *unclean*.

Comment: Also, this seems like a strange API design choice. *Just sayin'*

Comment: @AlexanderFlenniken I'd have to agree. Either the design is weird or the documentation is weird depending on which is correct..